# How to exclude a number be be selected from a random function?

Tags: php

I am trying to come up with the simplest code to generate a random number from a range but excluding one number, in this case "2".

Do I really need an "if" a "do" and a "while" to accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
$x = rand(1,5);
if ($x == 2) {  
    do {
        echo "The number is: $x <br>";
        $x = rand(1,5);
    } while ($x == 2);
}
echo "The number is: $x <br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the first two PHP lines , you only need the `do`. Also remove the `echo` inside the do.

Comment: Its time to take a break; I spend an hour trying to find out a better way!!!

Comment: Also you need a "seed" for you generator in order to get different random numbers on every execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$exclude = array(2);
while(in_array(($x = rand(1,5)), $exclude));
echo $x;
```

It works because the rand may return a variable in the array, which would then retrigger the while loop.

With this, you can build an array of all the numbers you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only excluding one number, replace it with an acceptable number that you don't include in the range.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
$x = rand(1,4); // accept 1, 2, 3 or 4 with equal probability
if ($x == 2) {  
    $x = 5; // if x = 2, change it to 5
}
echo "The number is: $x <br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would make the chances of the "random" number being 4 higher than anything else. If you exlude a number, you have a 1 in 3 chance to get any of the numbers. But with your code, you have a 1 in 4 chance to get any number except 4, where you have a 2 in 4 chance. That could be a major issue in some systems.

Comment: Why is that? my guess is that the probabilities will stay the same, right? If I pick a number from 1 to 5; if i select 2; i return the number to the bag and keep picking until a number different that 2 is selected!

Comment: True. I am used to Python where rand(1,4) results in 1, 2, 3 but not 4. I will edit.

Comment: @cronos because he isn't returning it to the bag, he is turning it into a different number.

Comment: Now `$x = rand(1,4);` will result in 1, 2, 3 or 4. (0.25 chance of each.) If a 2 is selected, replace with the 4. Sorry for the earlier solution (before the edit). I assumed rand(1,4) would only result in 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @fislerdata I see what you are saying, and that is one way to do it, but there are much more efficient ways.

Comment: @fislerdata ok, now i get it; that way is equal opportunities and the function only run once!